# How to insert data from one table to another in array format?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I'm setting up two Postgres tables table 1 and table 2.

Table 1 has a user_id and a name and description.
Table 2 has the same user_id as user and an array of name and description.

Now I want to insert data into name and description arrays of table2 from table1. All entries having the same user_id in table1 should have a single entry in table2 having user the same as that of user_id and the name and description arrays should have the rest data.

```
id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
user_id UUID NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR NOT NULL
)

table2(
id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
user UUID NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR [],
description VARCHAR [],
FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES table1 table1 (user_id) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
insert into table2 (id, user, name, description)
   select uuid_generate_v1(),  -- or whichever generation function you prefer
          user_id, array_agg(name order by id), array_agg(description order by id)
   from table1
   group by user_id;
```

Note the `order by` clause so the names and descriptions are in the same order in the arrays.